# Unable to create an azure cloud service using REST API

Tags: api, azure

I am trying to create an Azure Cloud service using the REST API in a C# application.  the XML used to describe the service is:

```
<CreateHostedService xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <ServiceName>AppHostingCloudService</ServiceName>
  <Label>base64-encoded-label-of-cloud-service</Label>
  <Description>This cloud service will host VMs</Description>
  <Location>Western-Europe</Location>
</CreateHostedService>
```

I did set up all headers correctly using the right certificate and all, I get an HTTP 400 error that says Bad Request, here is the details of the error:

```
+       response    {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 15:49:45 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 220
  Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```

Any ideas,

Thanks

Comment: Is the XML included in your question the actual XML you're sending or is it dummied up?

Answer (score 0):

400 Error usually means something wrong with the XML you're sending. Most likely it is the name of the datacenter location. You may want to get the list of locations by performing `List Locations` operation and see the right location name for Western Europe data center.